# Visual Studio 2012 C++ build failed but nothing on the error list or output

Tags: c++

Alright so I was a few weeks into this program with no error like this until I woke up this morning and tried to run the project again. When I try to run it the build fails however there is no error of any description in either the error list or the output views. I've checked and made sure that VS is showing all errors and commented out all new code from the passed few days that I added.

I even started a new project and tested different code and it worked just fine. I've looked around the net but I can't find anything of use. I'm hoping someone here might be able to shed a little light on this for me. The project is about 24 files at this point so I'm not sure if I can really post the code.

One thing I do know is that recently a friend of mine on the same network as me accessed the project to look at it from his computer. I have no idea if this would cause this problem but I guessed I should mention it just in case it is related. I should also note I have rebuilt the project twice with no effect. The only thing I know I can do is copy and paste the code to another project but I really don't want it to come to that. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you try restarting vis studio?

Comment: Did you try doing a rebuild solution?

Comment: Maybe try closing vs and deleting the .ncb file and manually deleting any intermediate folders (obj/ilk files etc).

Comment: Actually just noticed you said vs2012 - you wont have a .ncb!

Comment: I rebuilt it and that didn't help and I did restart visual studio several times.

Comment: I had something similar to this happen when I had not created either (I don't remember which) the intermediate file directory or the output file (.exe/.dll) directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove *.suo *.aps *.sdf in your project directory and remove Release or Debug directory which contains *.obj files.

then rebuild your project.

Comment: That worked thank you so much. I hate to bother but do you know why that worked? Is there somewhere I can read up on this so I can know what went wrong?

Comment: I am not sure why that happened, may be some one compile your project with different vs version and replace these temp files. when you encounter some curious problems in visual studio, try to remove these files, and try again.

Comment: My buddy who looked at the program does have a different version of VS so that was most likely the problem. Thank you once again for the help I really appreciate it.